# What number should be placed in that last slot?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, board-games

[image: The puzzle]

I came across a very difficult puzzle.
What number should be placed in that last slot?
I only know 16 is not the correct answer, because 11 is before 10.

Comment: Is this one of those (rot13) uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/15_chmmyr? If so this seems like it's one of those impossible-to-solve configurations.

Comment: No, it is not an impossible-to-solve configuration.

Comment: (rot13) Gnxr 15 guna chg 0 gurer, guna lbh pna fbyir gur 15 chmmyr

Comment: Welcome. Please can you clarify what the puzzle is. Have *you* put those numbers in that order, and we have find an extra number? Have you seen a picture of this puzzle and want to know how it works? To me this looks like a well-known type of puzzle where the task is to move the blocks around to get them in the *correct* order. There is meant to be a gap to allow room to slide blocks. In that case the final number doesn't exist.  Please explain, thanks.

Comment: @James - chasly above has done a good job trying to clear things up, but I'll extend on that. **I** believe that the "goal" of this puzzle is to slide the tiles around until they are in numerical order - [1 in the top left, reading left-to-right and top-to-bottom](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/15-puzzle-02.jpg/800px-15-puzzle-02.jpg). It has been shown that some inital starting positions are "unsolvable" - [link 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25563/46002), [link 2](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m31f13/public_html/15Puzzle.pdf)

Comment: (cont'd) **I'm not certain, as I haven't checked**, but this looks to me like one of those impossible starting positions. My answer to the question "what number should be placed in that last slot" is "nothing, and the puzzle that this is meant to be is actually unsolvable."

Comment: Update: just checked; this configuration is 'equivalent' to Sam Lloyd's famous "15 puzzle" which has been shown to be unsolvable. If this is meant to be a 15-piece slider puzzle (and it sure does look like one!) then it is unsolvable. The empty spot is meant to be empty, and the 10 and 11 pieces got swapped by pulling them out and putting them back in.

Comment: Back to the question, no number is placed in the last slot. It is empty so that the other tiles can be slid around. There isn't a 16 tile in the puzzle, so you can't be asking which of the two possibilities 12 or 15 should be the first move.

Answer (score 2):

You misinterpreted the puzzle. You shouldn't place a number in the last slot; you should move them around so that the numbers are in order, i.e. from the shown position you need to swap the 11 and 10. It's a type of sliding puzzle, more than a century old, known as the [15-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle). Half of the starting positions of this puzzle are unsolvable, as is this particular one. It's rather easy to obtain [Sam Loyd's position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle#/media/File:15-puzzle-loyd.svg) from this one.